# Format Date() in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have script then needs to get the date and time in this format  `08/25/2017 1:54 PM`

I write code for date

Here it is

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var dateNow = new Date();
    var dd = dateNow.getDate();
    var mm = dateNow.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = dateNow.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
    } 

    if(mm<10) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
    } 

    dateNow = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
    alert(dateNow);
});
```

But how I can get time in correct format?

Comment: `moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A")` ;) Don't reinvent the wheel and check out MomentJS

Comment: Works great. Thank's so much! @JeremyThille

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use :

```
dateNow.getHours()
dateNow.getMinutes()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you.

> It formats the date in your required format **08/25/2017 1:54 PM**

```
   var dateNow = new Date();
   var dd = dateNow.getDate();
   var mm = dateNow.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
   var yyyy = dateNow.getFullYear();
   if(dd<10) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
   } 

   if(mm<10) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
   } 

   var h =  dateNow.getHours(), m = dateNow.getMinutes();
   var _time = (h > 12) ? (h-12 + ':' + m +' PM') : (h + ':' + m +' AM');

dateNow = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy+ ' ' + _time;

alert(dateNow);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
var date = new Date(); 
var hours = date.getHours(); 
var minutes = date.getMinutes(); 
var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am'; 
hours = hours % 12; 
hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12' 
minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes; 
var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
var str = (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" +date.getDate()  + "/" + date.getFullYear()+ " " + strTime; 
console.log(str);
```