# Is there a way to format a Javascript data into dd-mm-yyyy?

Tags: javascript, typescript, datetime, datetime-format, kendo-datetimepicker

Currently I'm getting a date as from the kendo date-picker as such (1)`Sun Feb 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)`. However, I would like this date to format it in dd/mm/yyyy So I did the below logic to reflect my desired date. The below implementation, returns for instance the following date 26-01/2021 but in a string type. I would like to have a `Date` object but not in the way stated in the above date [(1)] but something like this `26 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT`.

Is this possible?

```js
  public static formatDate(dt: Date): string {
    const isValid = this.isValidDate(dt);
    if (isValid) {
      const formattedDate = dt.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
      day: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', year: 'numeric'
      }).replace(/\//g, '-');
      return formattedDate;
    }
    return null;
  }

  public static isValidDate(date) {
    return date && Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === "[object Date]" && !isNaN(date);
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format Date() in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45880161/format-date-in-js)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) for formatting date as per a particular locale.

The question mentions both `dd-mm-yyyy` and `dd/mm/yyyy` formats so here are two snippets that would help:

```js
public static formatDate(dt: Date): string {
  return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB').format(dt); // returns the date in dd/mm/yyyy format
}
```

```js
public static formatDate(dt: Date): string {
  return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB').format(dt).replace(/\//g, '-'); // returns the date in dd-mm-yyyy format
}
```

Comment: Note that the results of [*Intl.DateTimeFormat#format*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/format) are implementation dependent and may not return the result you expect.